# Google Script - Insert image in a Google Doc Table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to insert an image in a table in Google Doc replacing a text `%IMAGE%` inside the cell. 
I first get the table:

```
  var tables = body.getTables();
  var table = null;
  table = tables[3];
```

Then the rows and look for the text to substitute with my image (chart):

```
  var tablerows=table.getNumRows();
    for ( var row = 0; row < tablerows; ++row ) {
        var tablerow = table.getRow(row)
        for ( var cell=0; cell < tablerow.getNumCells(); ++cell) {
            var celltext = tablerow.getChild(cell).getText();
            if(celltext[cell]=='%IMAGE%'){
             celltext.removeFromParent();
             celltext.insertImage(cell, chart);
             }
         }
```

When I launch the script it doesn't find any error but it doesn't replace the text...
Any suggestion?

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution for this? I am running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

try this code. It search in every table for the replacing text and add the image inside the cell.

```
var tables = body.getTables();


 for (var k in tables)
 {
   var table = tables[k];
   var tablerows=table.getNumRows();
     for ( var row = 0; row < tablerows; ++row ) {
     var tablerow = table.getRow(row);
        for ( var cell=0; cell < tablerow.getNumCells(); ++cell) {
         var celltext = tablerow.getChild(cell).getText();

            if(celltext == "%IMAGE%") {
            table.replaceText("%IMAGE%", "");
            table.getCell(row, cell).insertImage(0, image);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

I still hope it's useful for you.